# Sql select statement while getting total of one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have following select statement

```
      select
      a.amount
      ,b.des
      ,a.id
      ,SUM(a.amount) as total
      ,b.id  
      from t_sales a
      left outer join t_location b on(b.id=a.orgId)
      where a.Id=@salesId   and
      a.sId=@supId
      GROUP BY a.amount, b.des, a.Id,b.id;
```

Everything is working fine, except total. I am trying to get total of a.amount which is returning 15 values so I want to have total of all 15 values. Please let me know how to fix it. 
Thanks

Comment: Does Amount in your query Include nulls?

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz No they are not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `a.amount` column from select list ( **aggregate column** should not exists in select list)

```
 select b.des, a.id, a.amount  ,SUM(a.amount) over(partition by 1) as total, b.id from t_sales a left outer join t_location b on(b.id=a.orgId)
    where a.Id=@salesId and a.sId=@supId GROUP BY b.des, a.Id, b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
select            a.amount, b.des, a.id, b.id,
                  (select            sum(a.amount)
                  from              t_sales a
                  left outer join   t_location b on (b.id = a.orgId)
                  where             a.Id = @salesId   
                  and               a.sId = @supId
                  GROUP BY          b.des, a.Id, b.id) as total
from              t_sales a
left outer join   t_location b on (b.id = a.orgId)
where             a.Id = @salesId   
and               a.sId = @supId
GROUP BY          a.amount, b.des, a.Id, b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select
    a.amount
    ,b.des
    ,a.id
    ,SUM(a.amount) over(partition by 1) as total
    ,b.id  
from t_sales a
    left outer join t_location b on(b.id=a.orgId)
where 
    a.Id=@salesId   and
    a.sId=@supId;
```